# Why does TypeScript not throw a compile error for an undefined type

Tags: typescript, react-native

Here's a simple repro to describe the problem:

1. I created a vanilla RN project using `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`
2. In `App.tsx`, I added `let foo: IThoughtTheWholePointOfATypeSafeLanguageWasNotToAllowShitLikeThis = "...seriously, wtf, why does this compile without an error!?";`
3. I run the app using `yarn iOS`

The app runs fine and there are no errors in the bundler.

Question: How do I make it throw a compile error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

`yarn tsc` does the compilation and generates type errors, if there are any. You can chain this as part of other commands in your `package.json` file, by preceding the existing command with `yarn tsc &&`, if you need to fail on type errors before invoking the intended command.

For example, one of the commands in my `package.json` is as follows:
`"test": "yarn tsc && rm -f __tests__/**/*.js && jest --coverage"`

The `rm` bit may be helpful to you, as I've noticed that running `tsc` generates `.js` versions of all your `.ts` files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--strict` in your compiler options.

This will:

> Enable all strict type checking options.
>   Enabling --strict enables --noImplicitAny, --noImplicitThis, --alwaysStrict, --strictBindCallApply, --strictNullChecks, --strictFunctionTypes and --strictPropertyInitialization.

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html